# Colab Notebook keeps disconnecting

Tags: google-colaboratory

I run a cell that executes many experiments and sends the results to my own server through ssh.

However, in every 15-30 minutes, my notebook disconnects from the server. And in 90 minutes, the VM shutdowns itself probably due to being idle. So, I have to restart the experiments in every 90 minutes but it should be something like 12 hours, right?

While a cell is running I cannot reconnect the server. I can only reconnect after VM gets closed without waiting the cell to finish its job.

I connect to Colab via University Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the free GPU? I'm not sure if that would help avoid your timeout but it will make your processing faster.

Select "Runtime," "Change runtime type," and set to GPU (the default is CPU).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the first things I did :)

Comment: that did not solve, I have a similar problem. My notebook keeps disconnecting randomly every couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you the keep the browser tab open and with focus on (click on it before leaving it opened) and the PC with the screen active.

I also have to execute code for many hours and with this "trick" I'm almost sure to find the VM up when I'm back on my PC. I said almost because for example last week I have been kicked out from the VM without any possibility to reconnect because of the GPU usage.

I reach the (free) limit, but after 9 hours of training, It's fair I think.

Answer (score 0):

Set a javascript interval to click on the connect button every 60 seconds. Open developer-settings (in your web-browser) with `Ctrl+Shift+I` then click on console tab and type this on the console prompt. (for mac press `Option+Command+I`)

```
function ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Connect pushed"); 
    document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);
```